# Serve ports through DS Lite router?

Tags: networking, router, ip, port-forwarding, webserver

OK. I am running an ssh service on port 22. Also, a java serverSocket on port 4444, but whatever. I was finally going to remotely access them. Enable WAN connection + forward to my port from the router? done. Got my IPv4 address from ipinfo.io, but `ssh IPv4`? ...connection timed out! `ping IPv4`?? no response!

After hours of googling, I found out my router has a DS Lite profile, ought to prepare the IPv6 networking of the future, but apparently not replacing ANY IPv4 capabilities.
It gives You an external IPv6, but still assigns local IPv4's.

What ipinfo.io's mysterious IPv4 is when router settings only displays the IPv6, I have no idea.

Seriously, is it really this hard or there is a way to access my ports? Solutions online have so far been to throw out the router, change provider, or quit being a nerd.

Comment: DS-Lite typically utilizes [CGN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT), thus leaving with no other option than upgrading your plan, changing the provider or use a VPN.

Comment: Thanks, just for the record I first posted this on stackoverflow by accident and a user there who I'll reference if I find out how also noted: "Your ISP agreement [...] forbids you from running any type of server to the public internet. [...] ISPs can no longer get IPv4 addresses from the RIRs, so they must share IP addresses among their residential customers (see CGN), saving IP addresses for business customers willing to pay for unique addressing, and this prevents you from doing what you want."

Comment: Still, if I may ask (not as if I was willing to violate the referenced terms), why do I have the option of forwarding ports on the router than, whatsoever? And why can I not even ping/ping6 the dear router?

Comment: The router is basically a firewall + switch + router (+ modem). It can work on many standards and connection types (real DSL, DS-Lite, behind a modem etc). It also forwards your port, but only to the next router, where they are blocked again.

Comment: i'm probably being stupid, but... I'm forwarding to.. my computer, not.. to a router... am i not?... i'm appreciating your comments!

Comment: Depends on how you are looking at it; you are right, you are forwarding the ports on from router to your PC. The router of your ISP has to forward the ports as well, though, and that's not happening.
It 's also discarding ICMP (ping) packets.

Comment: ah so that's the wall i'm banging my head into...

Comment: this will be off-topic but i'm dying: I switched network. Now it's a normal, IPv4 NAT router. What is the difference between me and [these](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/379959/how-do-i-ssh-from-school-computer-to-home-computer) guys, that everything works for them with a simple port forwarding? I tracerouted my router and it is only reached by --icmp. TCP and UDP hang up just before by router.

Comment: This would be a question to your ISP. Perhaps they don't allow traffic that hasn't been initiated by you in order to upsell on business contracts. Usual home internet package contracts typically exclude server hosting or hosting services for a profit.